# Android app run normal but Admob not display

Tags: android, admob

I have a problem, I integrated it does not display AdMob velvet . Everyone can help me?
This is the code I added de show ads .
add admob in activity_play.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlstatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fffd7a"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hitCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fffd7a"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/scoreCount"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSound"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sound" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgSound"
            android:src="@drawable/hint" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hintCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgSound"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
// them vao admob
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4506687331864737/xxxxxxxxx">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this code in PlayAtivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        //them vao admob
        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(PlayActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4506687331864737/xxxxxxxx");


        //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        //.addTestDevice("95F9D0E7976AC34B40EC660FF460782D") //Random Text
                .build();

        // Load ads into Banner Ads
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);


        LoadConfigParams();
        LoadSharedPreferences();
        LoadResources();
        LoadListeners();        
        LoadStage(mCurStage);
    //  LoadAds();
    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        // Call displayInterstitial() function
                        displayInterstitial();

                    }
                });

    }
    // goi admob

    public void displayInterstitial() 
    {
        // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
```

this is code in Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
// them vao quang cao
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>
```

it's running normal but not display admob.
Can anyone show me the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate whether you mean banner or interstitial ads.

You should look at your logcat. It will tell you what Admob is doing and why it is not displaying any ad.

And **NEVER** call `interstitial.show()` from `onAdLoaded()` unless you want your account banned.